# mysql get data from outside of while

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get some data from database with this code

```
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user     = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "test";

$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT author_id FROM user");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $sn=$data['author_id'];
}

$lastresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id='".$sn."'");
```

This code only work fetches one `author_id`

`$sn=$data['author_id']` and `$lastresult` works only with one `author_id` and doesn't fetches all the `author_id`.

How can I get data for all `author_id` ?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwritting `$sn` each loop.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT author_id FROM user");
$sn = [];
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $sn[] = $data['author_id'];
}

$sn = implode(',',$sn);
$lastresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id IN (".$sn.")");
```

PS: mysql_* functions are deprecated and has security issues. Consider replace with mysqli_* functions or PDO.

Comment: This really could have all been accomplished with one sql statement and a JOIN. Although, I'm confused about the whole idea, since if its grabbing every user, and then grabbing ever post by every user... its basically just `SELECT * FROM post` ... ?

Comment: I didn't understood either, but I was trying to follow the OP's way of thinking.